# No sections in MS Powerpoint "Outline" view?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, outline

**edit:** The answer seems to be no, and there is [a votable enhancement request for this](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/12244875-sections-visible-and-editable-in-outline-view).

---

In Powerpoint (2010, 2019), there is a sectioning feature with folding and there is an outline view. Given that sections are visible in both "Normal" view and the Slide sorter, I would expect them to be visible in the Outline View too, but they are not.

Is it possible to have sections displayed in the Outline view?

Or if that isn't possible, is there any other way to have only sections and slide titles in the sidebar? (Default is sections + thumbnails).

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately, but there are requests for this on UserVoice:  please visit and upvote:  https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/12244875-sections-visible-and-editable-in-outline-view

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Did already. I'm surprised there are not more upvotes. Will add the link to the question in hope of giving it more visibility.

Comment: Good idea, adding the link for upvotes.  I already upvoted it, btw.